# MDBTools: all queries fail

Tags: php, ubuntu-18.04, mdbtools

I'm moving a project to a Ubuntu server which connects to a Windows Server for a MS Access database via a shared folder which is mounted. I have installed MDBTools as driver, but currently all my queries seem to fail where on Windows they work fine. So I'm looking for a way to either fix the queries or install a different driver all together. Queries like this fail:

```
SELECT tableone.*, tabletwo.keyfromtabletwo, tabletwo.achternaam FROM tableone LEFT JOIN tabletwo ON tableone.somekeyfromtableone=tabletwo.keyfromtabletwo
```

It seems as if the . is what is giving the error because a query like this does work:

```
SELECT * FROM tableoneWHERE id=79365
```

While this doesn't:

```
SELECT tableone.* FROM tableoneWHERE id=79365
```

Hope my situation is clear? I don't mind changing the queries, but if someone know a better way I'm open to suggestions.